# Parse a string into line spaced rows based on delimiter using SQL

Tags: mysql, sql

Example :

```
"Status : Out of Service @-@ Cause : Partial @-@ Comments : "
```

the string should be divided as

- Status : Out of Service
- Cause : Partial
- Comments :

all the lines should appear in a single column in the same row in a table. Each column contains such string and each string should be parsed in such manner.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

One method uses `substring_index()`:

```
select concat(substring_index(col, ' : ', 1), ' : ',
              substring_index(substring_index(col, ' : ', 2), ' : ', -1)
             ) as status,
       concat(substring_index(substring_index(col, ' : ', 3), ' : ', -1),
              ' : ',
              substring_index(substring_index(col, ' : ', 4), ' : ', -1)
             ) as cause,
       concat(substring_index(substring_index(col, ' : ', 5), ' : ', -1),
              ' : ',
              substring_index(col, ' : ', -1)
             ) as comments
```